# Vuetify Data tables render problem with Safari

Tags: ios, macos, datatables, safari, vuetify.js

I know this one should be easy, but I haven't been able to find the problem yet. I´m using Vuetify Data tables with external source, all is ok on any browser but Safari (MacOS and iOS).

Problem: When Data table is larger than the viewport it cannot render the background color after the viewport.

You can check repo here (comes with demo):
https://github.com/davellanedam/vue-skeleton-mvp

Demo here: https://vue-demo.daniel-avellaneda.com

Credentials: admin@admin.com / 12345

Problem is at components adminCities.vue and adminUsers.vue

How to reproduce:
Start safari with small window, then scroll Data table, or get Safari into responsive mode and choose iPhone 8 and then scroll Data table.

Before scroll: https://i.stack.imgur.com/et5Lu.jpg

After scroll: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdEjR.jpg

Any clues on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

By removing style `max-width: 100%` from `table.v-table` in Safari devtools the problem is fixed. My workaround is overwriting that class:

```
<style>
table.v-table {
  max-width: none;
}
</style>
```